# How to send a content to specific users in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project that I want the admin to be able to send a file to a specific person and the information in this file is formed through a form.

Suppose an academic advisor has to send a separate syllabus to each of their students, which is a photo file. I have problems for every student in all areas such as database, downloading, uploading and displaying that image. I hope I could have explained it well

Please anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0):

you can use a table in your database and save address of each file for each user you want. also use GUID file name for files and if It Has secure thing you can use Webapi interface Download (disable directly download) that check permission every time api called

Comment: Yes that's right
I know this but I do not know how to send a photo to the first student and display it in the user panel of the first student and do the same for the other students. exactly the main problem in database design and database relations between admin and student

Comment: can you explian you senario? only first student can see it? amd second one not?

Comment: No The counselor sends the program to several students. My problem is that I do not know how to put these photos in the database. The relationship between the program and the student is one to one. So any program is for the student. Later, the student should be able to view and download this program in his user panel
I hope I can explain well